# How to implement a function that obtains the percentage corresponding to each counter?

Tags: javascript, html

The percentage will be updated depending on the two counters.  I have to have as total data the sum of counter and counter1

```
var botonElement = document.getElementById("botonClick");
var pElement = document.getElementById("areaContador");
var pPorce = document.getElementById("porcen");
var contador = 0;

var botonElement1 = document.getElementById("botonClick1");
var pElement1 = document.getElementById("areaContador1");
var pPorce1 = document.getElementById("porcen1");
var contador1 = 0;
botonElement.onclick = function () {
  contador++;
  pElement.textContent = contador;
  /*   pPorce.textContent = result + "%"; */

}

botonElement1.onclick = function () {
  contador1++;
  pElement1.textContent = contador1;
  /*   pPorce1.textContent = result + "%"; */
}
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO! Add what you expect and provide a minimal reproducible example, either with HTML or with some default values. Add console.log output to show what you current get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are looking for something like below.

```js
function increaseCounter(index) {
  const countElement1 = document.getElementById("counter1");
  const countElement2 = document.getElementById("counter2");
  
  const currentCountElement = document.getElementById("counter" + index);
  currentCountElement.value = parseInt(currentCountElement.value) + 1;
  
  const value1 = parseInt(countElement1.value);
  const value2 = parseInt(countElement2.value);
  const total = value1 + value2;
  
  const perc1 = ((value1/total) * 100).toFixed(2);
  const perc2 = ((value2/total) * 100).toFixed(2);
  
  document.getElementById("percentage1").innerHTML = perc1;
  document.getElementById("percentage2").innerHTML = perc2;
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #993355;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <h3>Area 1</h3>
    <div>Count: <input type="text" value="0" id="counter1" /></div>
    <div>Percentage: <label id="percentage1"></label></div>
    <div><button onclick="increaseCounter(1)">Click Here!</button></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>Area 2</h3>
    <div>Count: <input type="text" value="0" id="counter2" /></div>
    <div>Percentage: <label id="percentage2"></label></div>
    <div><button onclick="increaseCounter(2)">Click Here!</button></div>
  </div>
</div>
```